# Run unit tests on dynamically created DLL

Tags: unit-testing, dynamic, reflection, nunit

I am thinking on how to implement this , and seems like my knowledge is too poor to understand the implementation.

I have a code that compiles source code to DLL.

Then I need somehow to run Unit test on this Dll , and check 3-4 methods inside.

I am trying to run unit tests this way.

```
CompilerResults compileResults = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, new string[] { sourceCode });

            Assembly myAssembly = compileResults.CompiledAssembly;

            TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(@"TestingProject.dll");
            testPackage.Assemblies.Add(myAssembly);

            RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
            remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
            TestResult testResult = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(),TestFilter.Empty,false,LoggingThreshold.All);
```

And this for example Test

```
   [Test]
    public void AddTest(IDynamicScript s)
    {            
        Assert.AreEqual(10, s.Add(5,5));
        Assert.AreNotEqual(10,s.Add(4,5));

    }
```

Since Assembly is compiled dynamically , I can't reference it to unit test Project , and it will not compile , any suggestions please on how to implement this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine after a few modifications. These are the required changes:

- The test code needs to be wrapped in a class with appropriate namespace imports, you can't compile standalone methods with the C# compiler
- You need to inform the compiler about the assembly references of the code you're compiling, in this case I supplied the path to the `nunit.framework.dll` assembly, which I got from the location of the copy loaded in the main AppDomain, but you can also reference it from the file system without loading it. Usually you will also need to supply the paths of the assemblies containing the code you're testing
- The constructor of the `TestPackage` class takes an absolute path in its constructor, in this case I supplied the location of the generated assembly

This is the code with the corrections:

```
var sourceCode = @"
using NUnit.Framework;

public class Fixture
{
    [Test]
    public void AddTest()
    {            
        Assert.AreEqual(10, 5+5);
    }
}";

var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

CompilerResults compileResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    new CompilerParameters(new[]{ typeof(TestAttribute).Assembly.Location }), 
    new[]{ sourceCode });

var assembly = compileResults.CompiledAssembly;
var package = new TestPackage(assembly.Location);
var runner = new RemoteTestRunner();

runner.Load(package);

var result = runner.Run(new NullListener(), 
                        TestFilter.Empty, 
                        false, 
                        LoggingThreshold.All);
```

Comment: Simone thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it's not what I am trying to achieve. Your code pointed me to the new idea of how it can be done , but I'd like to ask you additional thing.

Comment: What i need to do is to allow our qa managers to write testing scripts for our system , I am giving them a template with code in TextArea, and they will write "test scripts" that will be C# Methods , They writing code in TextArea , then I am dynamically compiling their code to assembly , and I would like to be able to run unit test I'd prepared before , on this assembly , so assembly need to be "injected" into unit tests

Comment: But again thanks for your reply , it pointed me to the idea I will try to implement today.