# Unit testing of dynamically created assembly

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've asked similar question in past , but we put this thing aside , and we got back to the problem.
What we try to achieve it to run unit tests on dynamically created dll.

We have some API for QA engineers to insert scripts into our application. The QA enginner , writes some code in our application Editor , and then Code Compiled in runtime , and saved as assembly on disk.

We would like to be able run set of tests on this dynamically created assembly.
We are forcing our QA team to Inherit from some base class and override some methods , and these are methods we want to test...

How would you impliment this ? Any idea will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at existing topic to find answers: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145030/run-unit-tests-on-dynamically-created-dll][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145030/run-unit-tests-on-dynamically-created-dll

Comment: Those are also mine questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to inspect the types in the dynamic assembly and find those concrate types which derive from your base class. Assuming they all have parameterless constructors, you can do something like:

```
Assembly dynamicAssembly = //generated
var derivedInstances = dynamicAssembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)))
    .Select(t => (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(t));

foreach(BaseClass bc in derivedInstances)
{
    //run tests
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking from above you would need to create an instance of the classes defined in the dynamically created dll using some method (reflection is one way). Cast these objects to your base class type, and then you should be able to execute the methods of the base class.

What's more interesting in my opinion is: how are you going to define what is the correct result when you execute a method? I would say your QA engineers also need to specify the expected unittest results.